# How to convert row into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table i got the maximum and minimum record on each id. I have following query and output

```
SELECT s.Id, tabl2.X, tabl2.Y
FROM (SELECT MAX(tabl2.Id) AS tbl2Id, tabl1.Id
   FROM tabl2 INNER JOIN
   tabl1 ON tabl2.Id = tabl1 .Id
   WHERE (CONVERT(date, tabl2.date) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1))  and tabl1.Id=1
   GROUP BY tabl1.Id

   UNION

   SELECT MIN(tabl2.Id) AS tbl2Id,  tabl1.Id
   FROM tabl2 INNER JOIN
   tabl1 ON tabl2.Id= tabl1.Id
   WHERE (CONVERT(date, tabl2.date) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1)) AND and  tabl1.Id=1
   GROUP BY  tabl1.Id) AS s INNER JOIN
tabl2 ON s.Id= tabl2.Id

Id          X          Y 
1     73.1102528   33.545264
1     74.1240448   32.2604704
```

but i want output like this

```
Id             X           Y           X1           Y2
1          73.1102528   33.545264    74.1240448   32.2604704
```

Comment: Please check 'PIVOT' keyword in SQL

Comment: you could use a `Join` instead of an `Union` if the two tables has the same ID.

Comment: @Baalthasarr  what do you mean same ids.two table have one to many relation .table 2 contain the table1 id

Comment: In your example both SELECT statements return the same ID value (1), but like i saw right now, that is coincidence and can not be used as a join parameter

Comment: @Baalthasarr join parameters not work in my case,

Comment: @JayeshGoyani can you explain or explain with code.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your query, the min/max can come into a single statement as they are grouped on the same id. As follows:

```
select s.id, tabl2.x, tabl2.y
from (
    select max(tabl2.id) as tbl2id_max, min(tabl2.id) as tbl2id_min, tabl1.id
    from tabl2 
    inner join tabl1 on tabl2.id = tabl1 .id
    where (convert(date, tabl2.date) = convert(date, getdate() - 1)) 
    and tabl1.id = 1
    group by tabl1.id
) as s inner join tabl2 on s.id= tabl2.id
```

Its not however clear from your example where X1 and Y1 should come from.. Pivot would be used to turn rows into columns, but I don't see where these rows come from in your example.

In addition you are selecting X/Y from tabl2 in your example directly. This implies you don't need a pivot as you can already select them directly from your table.

Provide some more info and I will update this response.